# In vim, change color of splits without the cursor

Tags: vim, colors

How do I modify my custom colorscheme to make splits which do have the cursor change to a different color (I want to change the splits other than the one I am currently editing to be a muted gray rather than the same color as the split I am currently editing).

Comment: I've got only one cursor, in the current window.

Comment: This isn't really possible, since Vim doesn't let you change the background color or the default text color on a per-window or per-buffer basis.

Answer (score 1):

Vim uses the `Normal` highlight group for all window backgrounds. The only distinction for active vs. other windows is the `StatusLine` vs. `StatusLineNC` highlighting of the status line (i.e. the line below each window that separates the splits). That's all that Vim offers.

With a distinctive cursor, that should be enough to easily recognize the active window. Also, fading other windows is often counter-productive, because that makes it harder to refer to text displayed in them.

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of research, it seems that my original question isn't really possible. However, this solution comes close enough for my purposes:

```
autocmd WinEnter * setlocal cursorline
autocmd BufEnter * setlocal cursorline
autocmd WinLeave * setlocal nocursorline
setlocal cursorline
```

Essentially what this does is highlight the line the cursor is on in a nice way. Consequently a quick glance at the screen tells me exactly where the cursor is, and which window the cursor is in. Combined with the idea of a nice colors for `StatusLine` and `StatusLineNC` and it is quite workable.